# Update with concat when some fields are NULL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am doing a simple Update on a table whereby I concat three fields:

```
Update TableA concat(Field1,Field2,Field3)
```

The issue is that in some records one or more of the fields can be NULL. Those records do not end up with an Update field. In the following situation I'd like the first record's update Field to be `BobJones`:

```
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+
| Field1 | Field2 | Field3  | Update       |
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+
| Bob    | NULL   | Jones   | NULL         |
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+
| Mary   | Ann    | Smith   | MaryAnnSmith |
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+
| Bill   |        | Clinton | BillClinton  |
+--------+--------+---------+--------------+
```

But `Update` simply ignores it. I tried in that vein `Update IGNORE` and that failed too. Yeah I know I could do `Case When Then` thing but it gets more complex than I'd like in this situation and was hoping there was some version of 'Update IGNORE` that would work instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert zero length string for each NULL value, caught with `IFNULL` or `COALESCE`:

```
Update TableA concat(IFNULL(Field1,''),IFNULL(Field2,''),IFNULL(Field3,''))
```

[Here is a functional example](http://rextester.com/BYN98659)

Comment: Example helped a lot thank you, the original nvl was failing, the IFNULL  worked great.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql  use  ifnull

```
concat(ifnull(Field1,''),ifnull(Field2,''),ifnull(Field3,''))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is shorter to use:

CONCAT_WS('',Field1,Field2,Field3);

**Sample**

```
MariaDB []> SELECT CONCAT_WS('', 'Bob',NULL,'Jones',NULL), CONCAT_WS(' ', 'Bob',NULL,'Jones',NULL), CONCAT_WS('Bob',NULL,'Jones',NULL);
+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| CONCAT_WS('', 'Bob',NULL,'Jones',NULL) | CONCAT_WS(' ', 'Bob',NULL,'Jones',NULL) | CONCAT_WS('Bob',NULL,'Jones',NULL) |
+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| BobJones                               | Bob Jones                               | Jones                              |
+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
```